# Default folder command not working

Tags: windows-explorer, windows-registry

I recently tried some alternative file manager (qdir and others) and finally uninstalled all of them... but it seems to have broken something in registry.

I have error messages when trying to open a folder from an application. For example:

- The "Show folder" button in Chrome Download tad
- The "Explore to" item in tortoiseGit show log dialog contextual menu

In these cases, I get the following error message:
[image: This file does not have a program associated with it for performing this action. Please install a program or, if one is already installed, create an association in the Default Programs control panel.]

How can I get this back to work?

Additional information : after looking at TortoiseGit source code, it seem that the SHOpenFolderAndSelectItems function is called and is failing to open the folder

Comment: Have you attempted to reinstall the application in question?  That particular application uses numerous interconnections with File Explorer, the error you received indicates it should be reinstalled.

Comment: I don't want to reinstall it, and I want to understand why I get this error message

Comment: Might be worth running CCleaner reg key clean up

Comment: Have you checked the default file associations, as the message indicates? Otherwise, do a registry search for the programs you removed and change any entries to `explorer.exe` (with directory path, if appropriate).

Comment: What default association? I'm not trying to open a file, but a folder, and it's not configurable in the control panel

Comment: @spikey_richie, CCleaner did not solve the issue

Comment: @jaudo - You are getting the error because you have screwed up your file extension associations.  If you are not willing to try reinstalling the application then I cannot submit an answer to your question.

Comment: I tried a lot of file managers, I don't event remember which I tested

Answer (score 0):

HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT > Folder > Shell > (Default) had a value (openinexplorer++)
Clearing this string solved my problem